# How do I read data from files in different folders sequentially?

Tags: python, file

I need to analyze data from 16 folders with data for samples: Sample1, Sample2 and so on. Each of these folders has 11 txt files with spectres for 11 different angles(5,10,15,...,55 degrees) and 2 additional txt spectres for lamp and background. What I have to do is to plot 2d Angle vs Wavelength colourmaps, where the colour is defined by the reflection coefficient value, which is calculated using the main, lamp and background spectres. I've already managed to pull out the necessary column from a file, to list all of the files in a folder and some other stuff, but I don't know how to make Python automatically run through files and do what I've described.

```
angles_data = []
f = sorted_alphanumeric(os.listdir(path))
print(f)
fl = open(f[0])

for file in f:
    token = open(file)
    linestoken=token.readlines()
    tokens_column_number = 1
    resulttoken2=[]
    for x in linestoken:
        resulttoken2.append(x.split()[tokens_column_number])
        token.close()
    del resulttoken2[0]
    new_list= [float(i) for i in resulttoken2]
    angles_data.append(new_list)

print(angles_data)
```

Here `f` is the list with the file names in a folder. I want to go through all of them in a for loop, but the `token = open(file)` doesn't work, it says no such file or directory although it's definitely there. I suspect that I should write the full path but I can't because here I use the string variable `f[number]` for the name.
Did anyone do something similar? If yes, I would be grateful if you helped me.

Comment: Could be a job for a glob. Try something like `glob.glob('Sample*/*.txt')`or whatever fits your files and loop over the result. Make sure you change to the right folder first, it will make things easier.

Comment: As far as I understand, it gives me the list of files, which I already have.

Comment: I did, and there is still an error. Is there a way to insert a string variable into the path name?

Comment: The glob will give you a string that fits the file already. If you use `listdir()` you have to construct the complete path manually with string formatting or pathlib.

Comment: But how do I loop the glob itself? I need to change the folder in a loop, for example, 'Samplei', where i is the changing variable.

Comment: OK, I think I got it, thanks